# How to solve this error: Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): label, x, y, colour and group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting this error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1):
> label, x, y, colour and group

My data frame looks like:

```
structure(list(Timepoint2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("V0", "V1", "V7", "D0", "D0.12h", "D7", "TD", "D14"
    ), class = "factor"), cluster = c("90", "100", "110", "112", 
    "113", "114"), count_freq_ppt = c(0.0098039, 0.0098039, 
    0.0294117, 0.0098039, 0.0098039, 
    0.0098039)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code I am running is:

```
    CDR3_clust_plot <- ggplot(CDR3_clust_plot_df, aes(y = count_freq_ppt, x = Timepoint2, color = cluster, group = cluster, na.rm = TRUE)) + 
      theme_bw() + 
      geom_line() + 
      geom_point() + 
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 250, by = 25), expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 250)) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(y = "Total clone count per participant", x = "Time point", 
           title = paste0("IGH CDR3 total clone count (", vaccine, "; ", diagnosis, ")"), subtitle = paste0(IGHV, "; length filtered; clusters present in >", 100/dividend, "% participants")) + 
      geom_label_repel(data = subset(CDR3_clust_plot_df, Timepoint2 == "V7" & count_freq_ppt > 0), aes(label = cluster), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your error, but I also did not run the `labs` line because the object `vaccine` is not available and the `geom_label_repel` line because that function comes from some additional package that I do not have installed. I get an error "each group consist of only one observation`.

Comment: Neither `ggplot()` nor `aes()` take a `na.rm` argument. If you delete your `na.rm = TRUE` args, the error will go away. (`geom` functions do have a `na.rm` argument., but not `ggplot()` and not `aes()`.) That said, you may have additional issues... it's hard to tell with your sample data only having one timepoint.